# golang глобальная переменная для шаблона

Tags: golang

В php можно сохранить в сессию значение например `$_SESSION['userId'] = $userId` и потом использовать в любом шаблоне `<?php $_SESSION['userId'] ?>` Как это реализовуется в golang? Что бы не передавать переменную в каждый шаблон, просто это напряжно =) делать так `tmpl.Execute(wr, struct{"userId": userId})` в каждый шаблон на каждой странице

Comment: Насколько я знаю в стандартных пакетах такое не реализовано.

Comment: @Oma А если не стандартными пакетами, как реализовать, пример какой-то?

Answer (score 1):

Глобальные переменные в любом виде не приветствуются в Golang - потому что наверняка вы забудете защитить их от конкурентного доступа.

**Решение:**
Зарегистрировать функцию которая будет возвращать нужное вам значение https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs

Т.е. вы регистрируете сеттер и геттер для нужной переменой (внутри этих функций делаете защиту от конкурентного доступа) и пользуетесь методами доступа в шаблонах.

**Замечание:**
Ничто не мешает зарегистрировать функцию SESSION() возвращающую map. Но лучше так не делать (опять же map - конкурентно небезопасна). Дело в том что $_SESSION - это глобальная переменная в рамках текущего запроса, а в Go нет понятия "текущего запроса" - все запросы происходят одновременно, работают с одними и теми же данными.